# Creating a table in MS ACCESS 2007 without a primary key

Tags: ms-access

Can I do this?

The reason I want to do this is, I am importing data from a csv file to access, and during the import process it creates a lot of problems with the autonumber in access.

The tables are not going to be linked in anyway

Comment: What problems is it creating?

Answer (score 2):

A primary key is not mandatory. If you don't want one, don't add one!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but consider adding it back when you're done importing.  Otherwise you may run into issues when trying to do edits, deletes, etc.  If you want to be able to edit or delete the records after you've imported, then you'll want a primary key.  If you just need read-only access to the data after import, then you should be fine without a primary key.

Comment: Whoops, spoke off the top of my head on that one.  I do a lot with linked tables to MS SQL, used to having a timestamp data type.  Edited my answer.  Thanks.